# How to read a file line by line and get a some string in each line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to read a text file and print a string present in the file

Text file(Test.txt):

```
Start_set
START: XYZ
PASS: True
PASS: True
PASS: True
END: XYZ
START: PQR
PASS: True
PASS :True
END: PQR
START: ABC
PASS: True
PASS :True
END: ABC
End_set
```

Following is the python code:

```
file = open('Test.txt','r')
text = file.read()
output = text.split('START:')[1].split("\n")[0]
print out
```

Output:

```
XYZ
```

But i want to read each line of the file and print the values "XYZ,PQR,ABC" as output . My code prints only "XYZ".I tried with while loop but did not get expected output.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need lookout all occurrences of `START:`

Solution:

```
with open('Test.txt', 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line.startswith('START:'):
           print(line.strip().split('START:')[1])
```

Output:

```
 XYZ
 PQR
 ABC
```

Comment: @ ssudake what should i do if i want output "XYZ : PASS"? should i use split('PASS')[0] ?

Comment: Replace print line with `print("{0}: PASS".format(line.strip().split('START:')[1]))`

Comment: But PASS is constant in this case right..If we have FAIL: True. It should print FAIL, but above code will print PASS for all the cases